# How to use CKEditor on the front-end?

Tags: 6, wysiwyg

CKEditor do not work on one specific theme, it works fine in the back-end and also when I switch the theme.

When I look the sources, I get the JS & CSS, `ckeditor` class on textarea but not the injected code that CKE add under each textbox with `id="cke_edit-body"`.

What can be the sources of the problem?

I know it's not jQuery, I found similar issues but they were provoked by a custom jQuery update, I use 1.3.2

Comment: Did you also give your users permission to access the _text format_ associated with the body field in the content type? e.g. filtered_html, full_html, etc.?

Comment: I should verify that! Where can i modify thoses parameters?

Comment: I forget exactly what the text is in D6, but it'll be under something like "text formats" in the standard user permissions page

Comment: @Clive I do not see anything like that in the permissions page , i am testing in admin mode, so i should just see everything and i just see a textarea with no Ckeditor.

One strange thing is that i have the class "ckeditor-mod" added to my textarea

Answer (score 0):

On Input filter option (admin/settings/filters) you can check the user permission for each type of input filter you have on the site.

Then if you are using the WYSIWYG module, at admin/settings/wysiwyg you can check which type of editor is using each input filter.

If the WYSIWYG editor is working for anonymous user on one theme but not on the other, you could also check (with Firebug or Chrome DevTools) if there are Javascript errors. If that is the case, please, update this post with the error message.